# SORT CRITERIA not working properly

Tags: drupal

Running drupal 7.22, I need to add an option to sort to a view - Content type Lecture which is associated with Curses.

In the Curse page I need to display the Lecture in a certain order.

The Lecture are dispayed in the following way

```
print views_embed_view('lecture_list_of_online_courses','block', $node->nid);
```

I tried the following simple solution -

1. added field 'my_wight' to the lecture content type
2. added values from 1 to 10 according to the necessary order.
3. add SORT CRITERIA to the lecture_list_of_online_courses view

result: the view displayed in a sort that seems to have nothing to do with the values I added to 'my_wight'

I've been working with drupal many times before, and did this sort of things more than once.

I can get whats wrong with this.

here is the resulting SQL query from the View -

```
SELECT node_field_data_field_oc_forum_reference.nid AS node_field_data_field_oc_forum_reference_nid, node_field_data_field_oc_forum_reference.title AS node_field_data_field_oc_forum_reference_title, node_field_data_field_oc_forum_reference.language AS node_field_data_field_oc_forum_reference_language, node_field_data_field_oc_forum_reference.type AS node_field_data_field_oc_forum_reference_type, node_field_data_field_oc_forum_reference.comment AS node_field_data_field_oc_forum_reference_comment, field_data_field_lecture_weight.field_lecture_weight_value AS field_data_field_lecture_weight_field_lecture_weight_value, 'node' AS field_data_body_node_entity_type
FROM 
{node} node
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_oc_forum_reference} field_data_field_oc_forum_reference ON node.nid = field_data_field_oc_forum_reference.entity_id AND (field_data_field_oc_forum_reference.entity_type = 'node' AND field_data_field_oc_forum_reference.deleted = '0')
INNER JOIN {node} node_field_data_field_oc_forum_reference ON field_data_field_oc_forum_reference.field_oc_forum_reference_nid = node_field_data_field_oc_forum_reference.nid
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_lecture_weight} field_data_field_lecture_weight ON node.nid = field_data_field_lecture_weight.entity_id AND (field_data_field_lecture_weight.entity_type = 'node' AND field_data_field_lecture_weight.deleted = '0')
WHERE (( (node.nid = '175' ) )AND(( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('online_courses')) )))
ORDER BY field_data_field_lecture_weight_field_lecture_weight_value DESC
```

I cannot run this query - any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

First - for the SQL to work you must remove '{' and '}' from the query

Second - When creating the SORT CRITERIA, u need to chose 'Relationship' in the settings of the SORT CRITERIA